# individually minify JS and CSS in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, minify, yui-compressor, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I'm currently migrating a project to Visual Studio 2010 and am trying to figure out how to minify JS and CSS files **individually** on build.

In Visual Studio 2008 I used a [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en&displaylang=en) with a build task that referenced the [C# port of the YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/).  In Visual Studio 2010 Web Deployment Projects seem to have been integrated into the build process.  Now there is this [Microsoft AJAX Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/34488) in public beta and I'm more confused than ever.

I found [this blog post](http://jvance.com/blog/2009/10/20/ComparisonOfYUICompressorForDotNETToMicrosoftAjaxMinifier.xhtml) which makes the business with the Microsoft AJAX Minifier a non-starter because of CSS limitations.  This shouldn't be confusing...it should be a check box in Visual Studio 2010.

Is there a simple way do this with Visual Studio 2010?  What am I missing here people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should still be possible with VS2010 by editing the csproj aka msbuild file.

Taken from [this thread](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=66655) on CodePlex.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <JavaScriptFiles Remove="@(JavaScriptFiles)" />
  <JavaScriptFiles Include="../js/2.js"/>
</ItemGroup>
<CompressorTask
  JavaScriptFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
  ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
  PreserveAllSemicolons="False"
  DisableOptimizations="Nope"
  EncodingType="Default"
  DeleteJavaScriptFiles="false"
  LineBreakPosition="-1"
  JavaScriptOutputFile="../js/2.min.js"
  LoggingType="ALittleBit"
  ThreadCulture="en-au"
  IsEvalIgnored="false"/> 
<ItemGroup>
  <JavaScriptFiles Remove="@(JavaScriptFiles)" />
  <JavaScriptFiles Include="../js/3.js" />
  <JavaScriptFiles Include="../js/4.js" />
</ItemGroup>
<CompressorTask
  CssFiles="@(CssFiles)"
  DeleteCssFiles="false"
  CssOutputFile="../css/release.css"
  CssCompressionType="YuiStockCompression"
  JavaScriptFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
  ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
  PreserveAllSemicolons="False"
  DisableOptimizations="Nope"
  EncodingType="Default"
  DeleteJavaScriptFiles="false"
  LineBreakPosition="-1"
  JavaScriptOutputFile="../js/3.min.js"
  LoggingType="ALittleBit"
  ThreadCulture="en-au"
  IsEvalIgnored="false"/>
```

Comment: Or you can also use post-build events and have it run a custom msbuild file. :)